# Alternate pathway of Gabriel synthesis to prepare secondary amine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, amines

Can modifying the Gabriel synthesis, which is generally restricted to synthesis of primary amines, be used to synthesise secondary amines?

I have attached my idea regarding the synthesis (the final product obtained is a phthalic acid):

[image: synthesis pathway]

Comment: You cannot do the 2nd reaction using alcohol as solvent. It will react with the acyl chlorides/cyanides to give the diester

Comment: Some of these intermediates feel too unstable... Is there precedent for adding HCl across an acyl cyanide twice? Practically, reductive amination is probably a simpler way of getting to secondary amines.

Comment: The benzocyclicamide (just before adding $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$), is not stable. $\ce{HCl}$ would leave quickly, giving cyclic carboxyimine product.

Comment: W-K reduction does not work for formamides. This looks like a lot of trouble to go to when reductive methylation procedures are well precedented, work very quickly and in high yield.

Comment: @orthocresol I added HCl twice to display the intermidiate. I wanted to see if somehow, even if with difficulty, secondary amines could be prepared by Gabriel synthesis. Hence I proposed a mechanism, though I have realised that it is not efficient enough to be implemented practically.

Comment: @Waylander If some polar aprotic solvent, like DMSO, is used, can the succesive product be formed by reacting cyanide ion with the carbonyl carbon of the acid chloride?

Comment: DMSO reacts with acid chlorides

Comment: Why did alc. KCN replaced one chlorine atom from phthaloyl chloride?